# Show hide input element based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to show hide input element based on selection value of another element.

However I am unable to achieve it. I am not sure what is wrong I am doing.
The JS Fiddle is here :

https://jsfiddle.net/rovvLt9e/1/

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr id="type">
            <td height="30">Type</td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="type" value="Document" checked>Document &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="type" value="Parcel">Parcel
            </td>
        </tr>
        </br>
        </br>

        <tr id="height">
            <td height="40">Approx weight of consignment</td>
            <td>

                <select name="weight">
                    <option selected>200gms</option>
                    <option>200 - 500gms</option>
                    <option>500 - 750gms</option>
                    <option>750gms - 1Kg</option>
                    <option>1Kg - 5Kg</option>
                    <option> > 5Kg</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</br></br>

<div id="text"> text</div>
```

The Jquery is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#type').val() == "Parcel") {
        $('#height').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#height').hide();
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rovvLt9e/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using selector `#type input` , `.change()` event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var h = $("#height");
  $("#type input").change(function() {
    if (this.checked && this.value == "Parcel") {
      h.show();
    } else {
      h.hide();
    }
  }).change()
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rovvLt9e/6/

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `change` event to accomplish your task,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elem = $('#height');
  var radios = $(':radio[name=type]').change(function() {
    elem.toggle(radios.filter(":checked").val() == "Parcel");
  });
});
```

And note, you have to use attribute selector here as there was no element with id type.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/rovvLt9e/2/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no element with id `type`. Bind change event to `input[name=type]` and toggle visibility like following.

```
$('input[name=type]').change(function() {
    $('#height').toggle(this.value=="Parcel");
});

$('input[name=type]:checked').change(); //to set initial state
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rovvLt9e/5/)